# Join or Push Slices

Tags: go, slice

How can I join multiple slices of the same entity into one slice?
Or how do I push a new entity value into a slice of the entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The go-wiki has a collection of [SliceTricks](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks) that you will find useful.

For example,

Append Slice

```
a = append(a, b...)
```

Insert Value

```
s = append(s, 0)
copy(s[i+1:], s[i:])
s[i] = x
```

Push Value

```
a = append(a, x)
```

References:

[Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/):

[Slice types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)

[Indexes](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Indexes)

[Slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slices)

[Making slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

[Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)

[Slices: usage and internals](http://golang.org/doc/articles/slices_usage_and_internals.html)

Answer (score 4):

The append builtin does both of that for you. Use it like:

```
a := []int{1, 2}
a = append(a, 3)
b := []int{4, 5}
a = append(a, b...)
// a now is []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

If you need more information on how to use slices, I recommend reading [Slices: usage and internals](http://golang.org/doc/articles/slices_usage_and_internals.html).